# How to set button visible for role programmatically using Kotlin Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I wanted to make button visibe only for users with uid from `Admins` node, but somehow it doesn't work. That's the function for this(uid value is setting earlier and it is the uid of current user):

```
private fun checkAdmin() {
    val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/admins/")

    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener {
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) { }

        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            if (p0.exists()) {
                if (uid == p0.value.toString()) {
                    createNewButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                } else {
                    createNewButton.isEnabled = false
                    createNewButton.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

There is the part from JSON file:

```
"admins" : [ "rTXdtJsE7qPZRpWnwTGBAX7dIxx1","4kwOjCjkKvazfoMcZygfsn1byB72" ]
```

**[image]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution for your problem might be the following code:

```
val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
val adminsRef = rootRef.child("admins")
val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        for (ds in dataSnapshot.children) {
            val value = ds.getValue(String::class.java)
            if(value.equals(uid)) {
                createNewButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            } else {
                createNewButton.isEnabled = false
                createNewButton.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()) //Don't ignore errors!
    }
}
adminsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
```

To get those values, you need to loop through the `DataSnapshot` object.

Comment: `==` in Kotlin is `equals`. Using `==` for string comparison in Kotlin is perfectly valid. See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html

Comment: @Zoe Edited the answer accordingly. Thank you Zoe for that.

Comment: thank you! i've added a break statement for Visible part, because it starts to fetch all the snapshots, and now it perfectly works